# How can I retrieve information about disk volumes?

Tags: c#, windows

I was looking around for a tool to monitor the status of my software raid under Windows 2003 Server, but couldn't find anything suitable (i.e. not [grossly oversized](http://www.nagios.org/) or [needlessly complicated](http://www.monitorware.com/common/en/articles/software_raid_monitoring_windows_2003.php)). So I decided to just do it myself, it's nothing spectacularly difficult.

So how can I retrieve the status of the volumes programmatically? It's been a while since I fiddled with the Windows API and I couldn't find anything right off the bat using Google. I know I can use `diskpart /s` and parse its output, but that gets messy fairly quickly (although it does have some advantages).

Any pointers into the right direction are highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Win32 API is the (apparently only) way to go here, [Virtual Disk Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986750%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the magic word.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383037%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a good example in C++ that will get you started. The number of different COM interfaces was pretty confusing for me at first, but the [How Virtual Disk Service Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739923%28WS.10%29.aspx) article was of *great* help getting the big picture.

It's actually pretty easy. Despite never having done any serious C++ coding and never having even touched COM before, I was still able to get the basic functionality to work in a few hours.

Comment: Thats maybe not the only way, it is the best way, and also what diskpart is using under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check WMI?

You can take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/wmi.aspx) for a demo.

Comment: WMI doesn't return the raid status (see http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/dedicated/monitoring_windows_software_raid)

Answer (score 0):

You could try monitoring the Event log for RAID events.

Comment: Yes, that's another option (see one of my links above). I'd rather query the status directly, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if RAID stuff will complicate matters, but I've used System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives() before and that's worked fine for my needs.